# How to use the same method with two different forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters

To clarify: I have two forms that use the same method in my Controller, and I was wondering how to use the same lines of code rather than copying and pasting the method and using a different parameter for each method.

Eg. What I have now:

```
public static void PopulateOriginCombo(CableID_QueryView QView)
{
    if (QView.cmbAreaCode.Text != "")
    {
       //Code...
    }
}

public static void PopulateOriginCombo(CableID_CreateView CView)
{
    if (CView.cmbAreaCode.Text != "")
    {
       //Code...
    }
}
```

Can I combine the parameters of each form into one somehow?

Comment: You could use inheritance or an interface.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil Yes, added the tag

Comment: @phoog I want to avoid inheritance if I can help it...

Comment: And what type is `QView` and `CView`? And whats the reason behind avoiding inheritance?

Comment: Avoiding inheritance is [often] good. Use an *Interface* that exposes `string AreaCode {get; [optional set;]}` as appropriate and/or deal only with raw input/output values. (I recommend exposing values and not Controls in interfaces, when applicable.)

Comment: @phoog I'm practicing what I call "Sideways programming". If I remove as much dependency or inheritance as possible there's less chance of the program creating problems when things break.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to avoid inheritance, create an interface:

```
interface IHasOriginCombo
{
    ComboBox cmbAreaCode { get; }
}
```

then, in your class declarations, add the interface:

```
class CableID_QueryView : Form, IHasOriginCombo { //...

class CableID_CreateView : Form, IHasOriginCombo { //...
```

then:

```
public static void PopulateOriginCombo(IHasOriginCombo view)
{
    if (view.cmbAreaCode.Text != "")
    {
       //Code...
    }
}
```

Comment: I would avoid inheritance anyway .. the first line makes it sound that using interfaces (or avoiding inheritance) is somehow "bad". Anyway, I would probably expose the *value* and not the ComboBox itself.

Comment: @user2864740 I didn't mean to imply that at all.  But exposing the value vs. the control depends on the level of abstraction at which you are operating.  If you implement the interface to expose the value only, and there is no inheritance, then you have to repeat the lower-level code that moves the value into and out of the combo box.  So the interface I propose is for use in the lower-level code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use inheritance to do this. Create another class which contains your methods and returns list of objects, then use it on different forms.

```
public class Origin
{
    public string originName { get; set; }

    public static List<Origin> PopulateOriginCombo(CableID_QueryView QView)
    {
        if (QView.cmbAreaCode.Text != "")
        {
           //Code...
        }
    }

    public static List<Origin> PopulateOriginCombo(CableID_CreateView CView)
    {
        if (CView.cmbAreaCode.Text != "")
        {
           //Code...
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your form, call it like this:

```
combo1.DataSource = Origin.PopulateOriginCombo(test);
combo1.DisplayMember = "originName";
```

Using objects is hard at first, but eventually you will find it easier to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

how about create class that has this method than you can call this method :

```
public static string PopulateOriginCombo(CableID_CreateView CView)
{
   if(CView != null)
   {
       if (CView.cmbAreaCode.Text != "")
      {
         return CView.Text ;
      }
  }

  return string.Empty;
}
```

than just create object from that class and call this method and pass the CView to it like that :

```
SomeClass classObject = new SomeClass();
string value = classObject.PopulateOriginCombo(this.CView);
```